# Word count problems

Tags: c, string, return-value

I'm trying to finishing one of my C homework questions. Here's the definition and sample IO:

Description

Given an article as input. You have to count the number of each word, and prints the list of words in alphabetical order.

Sample Input

> It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of
>   wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it
>   was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the
>   season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of
>   despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we
>   were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other
>   way.

Sample Output

```
age 2
all 2
before 2
belief 1
best 1
darkness 1
despair 1
direct 2
epoch 2
everything 1
foolishness 1
going 2
had 2
heaven 1
hope 1
incredulity 1
it 10
light 1
nothing 1
of 10
other 1
season 2
spring 1
the 11
times 2
to 1
us 2
was 10
way 1
we 4
were 2
winter 1
wisdom 1
worst 1
```

And this is my code now:

in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "function.h"
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char wordcollected [3100] = {0};
    char *word_ptr[100];
    int countarray[100];
    static char temp[31];
    int nth_word = 0;
    while(1){
        int n = strlen(wordcollected);
        word_ptr [nth_word] = wordcollected + strlen(wordcollected);
        if(strcpy(temp, fetch_word()) == NULL){
            for(n == strlen(wordcollected); n >= 0; n--){
            if(wordcollected[n] == ','){
                wordcollected[n] = '\0';
            }
        }
            break;
        }
        strcat((wordcollected), temp);
        strcat((wordcollected), ",");
        nth_word ++;
    }

}
```

Our TA have already finished partial codes for us:

in function.c:

```
#include "function.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// fetch words from stdin
const char *fetch_word(){
    static char skip_symbol[] = " \t\n,.;:?()[]{}\"\"''" ;

    static char line_buffer[1024] ;
    static char *now = NULL ;

    // try to read a line from stdin
    for( ;; ){
        if( now == NULL)
            now = fgets( line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), stdin ) ;

        // End Of File?
        if( now == NULL )
            return NULL ;

        // skip symbols
        for( ; *now ; now++ ){
            int size = sizeof( skip_symbol ) ;
            int i ;
            for( i=0 ; i<size ; i++ ){
                if( *now == skip_symbol[i] )
                    break ;
            }

            // if not match skip_symbol[]
            if( i >= size )
                break ;
        }

        // End Of Line?
        if( *now == '\0' ){
            now = NULL ;
            continue ;
        }

        char *word = now ;

        for( ; *now ; now++ ){
            int size = sizeof( skip_symbol ) ;
            int i ;
            for( i=0 ; i<size ; i++ ){
                if( *now == skip_symbol[i] )
                    break ;
            }

            // if match skip_symbol[]
            if( i < size )
                break ;
        }

        if( *now ){
            *now = '\0' ;
            now ++ ;
        }

        return word ;
    }

    return NULL ;
}
```

In function.h:

```
#ifndef __FUNCTION_H__
#define __FUNCTION_H__

// fetch words from stdin
const char *fetch_word() ;

#endif
```

The function *fetch_word() will return a pointer points to each word in stdin while running, and will also return NULL if the function already reaches the End-Of-File. But everytime when it reach to EOF, it just keep saying segmentation fault and the system halted. How can I detect the return value of fetch_word(), know when I reached the End-Of-File, and also prevent from losing any words?

Comment: Same homework as this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861396/my-system-just-keep-getting-crashed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to break at the end sign before you do the cycle:

```
    if(strcpy(temp, fetch_word()) == NULL){
        break;
        for(n == strlen(wordcollected); n >= 0; n--){
        if(wordcollected[n] == ','){
            wordcollected[n] = '\0';
        }
    }
    }
```

But take my advice and refactor your code and make it more readable. You will save yourself a lot of time that way.

Also, algorithmically, for me it seems that you might want to create a linked list of words, paired with a number (implement the linked list data structure to achieve that) and whenever you read a word, try to find it in the linked list until you reach something lower than the word alphabetically or the end of the list, or a match. If you find a match, add 1 to the number. Otherwise insert the word with 1 as value at its corresponding place.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching words, you can use following fetch_words().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_word(const char *word, void *arg)
{
    printf("[Word] <%s>\n", word);
}

/*
 * @fp   file pointer
 * @func recall function whch has two params (word, arg)
 * @arg  the second param of func
 * */
void fetch_words(FILE *fp, void (*func)(const char *, void *), void *arg)
{
    char area[256] = {0};
    char buff[128];
    int size = sizeof(buff) - 1;
    char *delim = " \t\n,.;:?(){}\"'";
    char *last;
    char *token;
    int len;
    char *pos;

    while (fgets(buff, size, fp) != NULL)
    {
        /* Append part of buff into area */
        len = size - strlen(area);
        strncat(area, buff, len);
        pos = area + strlen(area);

        /* Split string in area */
        if ((token = strtok(area, delim)) != NULL)
        {
            last = token;
            while ((token = strtok(NULL, delim)) != NULL)
            {
                func(last, arg);
                last = token;
            }

            if (last + strlen(last) == pos)
            {
                /* Copy last token into area  */
                strcpy(area, last);
            }
            else
            {
                /* Clean area */
                area[0] = 0;
                func(last, arg);
                last = NULL;
            }
        }

        /* Append left part of buff into area for next loop */
        if (len < strlen(buff))
        {
            strcat(area, buff + len);
        }
    }

    if (last)
    {
        func(last, arg);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    fetch_words(stdin, print_word, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

For word counting, you can use hashmap (**Key**, **Value**). **Key** is word, and **Value** is count of word.

Here is a simple implementation of hashmap in C:
https://github.com/foreverpersist/hashmap